# Change all read only fields background color in Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, styles, vuetify.js

My goal is to make all read only input fields distinguishable for my users. Currently, in Vuetify 2.0.12 readonly `<v-text-field>` and `<v-textarea>` components are indistinguishable from non read only fields.

I would like to globally change the background color, and text color of all `<v-text-field>` and `<v-textarea>` components that have the readonly prop.

example :

```
background-color = yellow lighten-3

text color = black
```

This needs to work for both light/dark themes as my application allows the user to choose their theme.

My CSS/Sass knowledge is extremely lacking so I apologize for such a rudimentary question. Feel free to suggest a better approach as well. What is a good way to "signal" to my users that this field is readonly?

Answer (score 4):

You can assign properties to a readonly selector like that:

```css
.v-textarea textarea[readonly="readonly"] {
    background-color: yellowgreen
}
.v-text-field input[readonly="readonly"] {
    background-color: yellowgreen
}
```

If your component style is scoped, add `/deep/` before : `/deep/ .v-textarea ...`

Comment: There are a couple side effects to this solution. Create a project and add a ```<v-select>``` element, you will notice the background color for this is also yellowgreen. Any way to make this specific to just ```<v-text-field>``` and ```<v-textarea>``` components?

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @ManUtopiK has some issues with other components, especially with selects.
This should fix them

```css
.v-textarea textarea[readonly="readonly"] {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: gray;
}
:not(.v-select).v-text-field input[readonly="readonly"] {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP is using Vuetify 2.0.12 but I landed here from a Google search and I'm using Vuetify 3.0.5. This is what I used in Vuetify 3.0.5 to target the v-text-field's outlined styling when readonly:

```
.v-field__field:has(input[readonly]) + .v-field__outline .v-field__outline__start,
.v-field__field:has(input[readonly]) + .v-field__outline .v-field__outline__notch::before,
.v-field__field:has(input[readonly]) + .v-field__outline .v-field__outline__notch::after,
.v-field__field:has(input[readonly]) + .v-field__outline .v-field__outline__end {
    border-color: red;
}
```