# How to style only non-readonly v-switch

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have the following:

```
<v-switch
  inset
  name="foo"
  label="foo"
  disabled
/>
```

and

```
<v-switch
  inset
  name="bar"
  label="bar"
  :readonly="true"
/>
```

In Vuetify 2, the disabled switch kept the primary color, but the readonly switch would be grey. I'm trying to get the same behavior on Vuetify 3.

If I do this:

```css
.v-input--readonly .v-switch__track, .v-switch__thumb {
  color:rgb(var(--v-theme-primary))
}
```

Then that results in the readonly no longer being grey, which isn't what I want

But this makes all the switches the primary color:

```css
.v-switch__track:not(.v-input--readonly), .v-switch__thumb:not(.v-input--readonly) {
  color:rgb(var(--v-theme-primary))
}
```

I've perused quite a few Stackoverflow posts and not managed to find anything that works. A few of those links, for reference:
[Change all read only fields background color in Vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823399/change-all-read-only-fields-background-color-in-vuetify)
[Override disabled style on v-btn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70785151/override-disabled-style-on-v-btn)
[Set Styles for disabled Mat-Expansion Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416768/set-styles-for-disabled-mat-expansion-panel)
[How to change/override the default color of a switch label in vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373084/how-to-change-override-the-default-color-of-a-switch-label-in-vuetify)
[How to change vuetify checkbox label style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990386/how-to-change-vuetify-checkbox-label-style)

No combination of `:not`, `:has`, `disabled`, `:disabled`, `aria-disabled`, `input[aria-disabled]`, `input.aria-disabled`, `[aria-disabled=true]`, etc, seems to work. Possibly because of this: [css :not(), selectors and selecting descendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227375/css-not-selectors-and-selecting-descendants)

My best guess is the issue is that it's the `VSelectionControl` that actually has `aria-disabled`, but similar css tweaks with `.v-selection-control` haven't yielded fruit.

Comment: On a related note, I'm struggling to style a disabled VTextField label without styling the input itself. The closest I've managed is `.v-field--disabled { opacity: .75; }`... it seems that in Vuetify 2, there was `.v-label--is-disabled` but I can't figure out the equivalent. `.v-text-field:deep(.v-field--disabled) .v-field-label { opacity: 0.75; }` doesn't work, either.